# Firebase Dynamic link is not opening IOS application

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have followed all the steps from the Firebase Dynamic links documentation:

1. Added Team Id to firebase console
2. Added custom domain
3. Enabled Associated domains
4. Added to Info URL Schemes

However, when I click on dynamic link it always redirect to AppStore not to the app. I have tried to unistall app, restart phone and install again. How to make this deep link work?

P.S: my app is not published to AppStore yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was that I made a typo in Associated domains in Xcode, instead of `applinks`, I typed 'applink'.